# React-Native Inifinite Scroll Both Directions

Tags: react-native

I want to create a ReactNative ScrollView that is infinite in both  directions (up and down). It can be implemented in ScrollView or ListView, either is fine to me.

I have already tied something similar to this:

```
  <ScrollView
    onScroll={this.addItemsIfTopOrBottom}
    onContentSizeChange={this.persitLastScrollPositionIfNeeded}
  >
    ...
  </ScrollView>
```

The problem in my case is, it renders the new content and displaces the old content, and even though I scroll to the appropriate position (without animation), there is a millisecond of the new content showing.

Comment: I did something similar with my app, but had to use two `ScrollView`s and set one to `horizontal={true}`

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying. My wording is off. When I say "both directions", I mean both up and down

Comment: @chapinkapa did you find a solution to do that? I'm stuck here...